# Is it safe to call publishProgress() in AsyncTask after app has been stopped?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle

I have an AsyncTask running. If the application is **stopped** (phone call, app switch etc.) my understanding is that onPostExecute() will never be called. So, as long as **cancel(true)** is used to cancel an AsyncTask, the running task will be notified of the cancellation. I don't mind having to check **isCancelled()** periodically in **doInBackground()**, but what concerns me is the **publishProgress()** calls that are littered throughout doInBackground. My understanding is that **onProgressUpdate()** runs on the main UI thread.

Does that mean that any calls to **publishProgress()** will crash the app if it has been stopped? Or is it just any UI updates *within* onProgressUpdate() that will cause a crash when the app has been stopped.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm wondering if I have to qualify each **publishProgress()** call with a check for **isCancelled()** or can I just check once in **onProgressUpdate()** before actually attempting to update any UI components.

Comment: I'll wait for someone else with more experience than me to chime in here, but based on some tests that I've run, it would seem that the answer to my question is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android documentation states:

> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) will not be called if the task has been canceled.
>   [developer.android.com/...AsyncTask#publishProgress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29)

Comment: That's great, so it's definitely safe to let publishProgress() calls do their thing when the task has been cancelled, it just won't have any effect. Thanks.